# Changing Segments Alters Cell Height - How do I revert back?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, custom-cell

I have a UISegmentedControl with 2 segments.  I'm loading JSON data into a table view and each segment has different data.  I first load the view and the default first segment shows up - data is there and cell height is perfect.  When I tap on the second segment, all is well, the data loads properly and the cell height now matches this set of data.  However, when I go back to the first segment the cell height is from the second, which is not what I want.  Ideally the cells will resize for the first segment data like it originally did.

**When I return to the first segment, how can I re-adjust the cell height so the data displays properly again?**

Answer (score 1):

You should implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

delegate method. and return the hight you want there.

Comment: Thanks Refael.  I have that method already, which does the job when i first go to each segment.  However, when I go back to the first segment (from the second) it still uses the second segments data to adjust the height.  Which is not desirable.  Maybe somehow I need to reload the data from the first?